# Sentence-Usage : "How long has this been empty for?" Or "How long was this empty for?"

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-perfect, past-simple

I'm asking this because I have a feeling that if I say **How long has this been empty for?** , It would be like an ongoing action. For example:

> A: How long has the dog's bowl been empty for?
>
> For about an hour (it's still empty).

But, I feel that it's "grammatically wrong" if I Say **How long was this empty for?** without having a time expression. But, if I say using the present perfect, it'll be an ongoing action (And I don't want this). I want to say this:

> A: *Fills the dog's bowl with food*
>
> A: How long this **has been**/**was** empty for?
>
> B: For about one hour.

but if I use the past simple, I think it will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I feel that it's "grammatically wrong" if I Say How long was this empty for? without having a time expression.

There is nothing wrong here with the grammar.

The choice of the tense depends on context.

If you are asking that question, to your friend, pointing at the empty bowl, then it should be

> How long **has** the bowl **been** empty for? *[It is still empty at the time of asking the question]*

If you are in the act of filling the bowl up or have already filled up, then you say

> How long **was** this empty for? *[The bowl is not empty anymore; you have filled it or, you are filling it]*

Compare the following:

> How long **have** you two been **married** for? *[Still happily married]*
>
> How long **were** you two married for? *[Still happily married]*